# Invalid Token in Jdeveloper with BPM 11G

Tags: java, soa, jdeveloper, business-process-management

I'm working with Oracle BPM 11G(11.1.1.7) and Jdeveloper.

I am getting below error while creating BPM MDS, my database and my SOA-MDS are working perfectly for a connection.

Only when I try to create the BPM-MDS error happens

```
Test Failed: ORABPEL-30503
Invalid Token Error in Verification Service.
Invalid Token Error in Verification Service. Received invalid token in null.
Verify that correct token is passed.

   at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateContextToken(VerificationService.java:1769)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateContext(VerificationService.java:1662)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateContext(VerificationService.java:1969)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.common.WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.invoke(WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy243.validateContext(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.impl.SecurityService.validateContext(SecurityService.java:237)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.impl.SecurityService.getSecurityService(SecurityService.java:247)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.impl.SecurityService.getPrincipal(SecurityService.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.common.WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.invoke(WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy270.getPrincipal(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean.getPrincipal(SecurityServiceBean.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy269.getPrincipal(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean_z7zjfk_ISecurityServiceRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:40)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean_z7zjfk_ISecurityServiceRemoteImpl.getPrincipal(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean_z7zjfk_ISecurityServiceRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.Exception: Null token
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateContextToken(VerificationService.java:1769)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateContext(VerificationService.java:1662)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateContext(VerificationService.java:1969)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.common.WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.invoke(WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy243.validateContext(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.impl.SecurityService.validateContext(SecurityService.java:237)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.impl.SecurityService.getSecurityService(SecurityService.java:247)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.impl.SecurityService.getPrincipal(SecurityService.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.common.WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.invoke(WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy270.getPrincipal(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean.getPrincipal(SecurityServiceBean.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy269.getPrincipal(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean_z7zjfk_ISecurityServiceRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:40)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean_z7zjfk_ISecurityServiceRemoteImpl.getPrincipal(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.bpm.services.pml.ejb.SecurityServiceBean_z7zjfk_ISecurityServiceRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Could someone help me, I'm very difficult to find a solution for this problem!!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? I am getting exact same error, in a custom worklist portlet.

Comment: I still can not solve this problem, if you have any evolution please post also

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved. I ended up generating my own web service proxy services for the TaskService, instead of using the one that was bundled with jDeveloper. So honestly speaking, because of time constraints, I did not get a chance to fix the exact root cause of this error. After generating this webservice proxy/stub, i bundled it as a shared webapp library and my Custom Worklist portlet refers to this library. This worked for me.

I used this WSDL to generate the proxy classes and then used the generated classes/methods to query tasks data.

```
http://soa_host:soa_port/integration/services/TaskQueryService/TaskQueryService?wsdl
```

Also, later taking the original case forward, I was also able to get around the token problem by using RMI/EBJ provider ( t3://: ) instead of SOAP binding (http://:).

Here's what my code looks like :

```
String serverUrl ="t3://soa_server:soa_port"; // host:Port of the soa server
Map<IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY, String> connProperties = new HashMap<IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY, String>(); 
connProperties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.CLIENT_TYPE,WorkflowServiceClientFactory.REMOTE_CLIENT); 
connProperties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.EJB_PROVIDER_URL,serverUrl);
connProperties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.EJB_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
IWorkflowServiceClient wfSvcClient = WorkflowServiceClientFactory.getWorkflowServiceClient(connProperties, null, null);
ITaskQueryService querySvc = wfSvcClient.getTaskQueryService();
IWorkflowContext adminCtx = wfSvcClient.getTaskQueryService().authenticate(adminID, adminPass.toCharArray(), "jazn.com" );
IWorkflowContext userCtx =   querySvc.authenticateOnBehalfOf(adminCtx, userID);
List displayColumns = new ArrayList();
displayColumns.add("TASKNUMBER");
displayColumns.add("TITLE");
displayColumns.add("STATE");
displayColumns.add("CREATOR");
List optionalInfo = new ArrayList();
optionalInfo.add("Comments");
optionalInfo.add("Payload");
tasks=querySvc.queryTasks(userCtx, null, null, ITaskQueryService.AssignmentFilter.MY,null, null, null, 0, 0);
```

This returns list of tasks assigned to the user whose ID you send to authenticateOnBehalfOf() method call above.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution from Oracle Support Documentation fixed the issue for me. In summary, it's a jar mismatch between server and jdev that caused the issue.

=========================================================================

You are unable to get the BPM context successfully. There will not be an exception while retrieving the context but when trying to use it you see the exception:
BPM-70684

Exception
exception.70684.type: error
exception.70684.severity: 2
exception.70684.name: Invalid authentication context.
exception.70684.description: Invalid authentication context has been passed.
exception.70684.fix: Ensure valid authentication context is passed.

The following exceptions have known to be associated with the same issue:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.WorkflowContext.hashCode(WorkflowContext.java:583) 
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:300) 
at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.common.ThreadLocalCache.isContextValidated(ThreadLocalCache.java:146) 
at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateNotNullWorkflowContext(VerificationService.java:1824) 
at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.VerificationService.validateContext(VerificationService.java:1806)

Error while authenticating on behalf of user weblogic using adminContext [user=null][sessionKey=null][token=null][requester=null][objectId=null]
    <<.> Verification Service cannot resolve user identity.
User null cannot be found in the identity repository.
Workflow Context token cannot be null in request.

ORABPEL-30511

Verification Service cannot resolve user identity.
User null cannot be found in the identity repository.
Workflow Context token cannot be null in request.

at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.LocalCacheManager.lookupUser(LocalCacheManager.java:600)

Caused By: ORABPEL-10501

Illegal argument.
Illegal argument.
This is because an unexpected value, possibly null, was passed as an argument. Check the error stack and fix the cause of the error. Contact Oracle Support Services if error is not fixable.

at oracle.tip.pc.services.identity.jps.AuthorizationServiceImpl.lookupUser(AuthorizationServiceImpl.java:236)
at oracle.tip.pc.services.identity.jps.IdentityServiceImpl.lookupUser(IdentityServiceImpl.java:183)
at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.verification.impl.LocalCacheManager.lookupUser(LocalCacheManager.java:596)

We are embedding a BPM task Flow list in an ADF App. It gives the following error
infra] <.> Invalid Token Error in Verification Service.[[
Invalid Token Error in Verification Service. Received invalid token in null.
Verify that correct token is passed.
ORABPEL-30503

Also, If you log the username from the context you'll notice it is null.
Cause

The bpm-services.jar on the client application and the server may not match.  The SOA/BPM related jars being used on the client and server must be the same or unexpected issues can occur.

Solution

1. Copy the bpm-services.jar from the server
2. Replace the bpm-services.jar on the client application with the one from the server
3. Ensure that after any patches are applied that the jars on the server are replaced in the client application.

This also applies to using jars within JDeveloper which can become out of sync due to patches not being applied on both dev and server machines. You may need to replace the bpm-services.jar located here JDeveloper/soa/modules/oracle.soa.workflow_11.1.1/bpm-services.jar  with the one located here [soa_install_dir]/soa/modules/oracle.soa.workflow_11.1.1/bpm-services.jar.